# snowflake stored procedure giving error like "Uncaught ReferenceError"?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have tried to execute below query it is throwing error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: float_param1"

```
create or replace table test1(num_col1 number);

create or replace procedure rt(float_param1 float )
returns string 
language javascript 
as
$$
var sql_command=
 "insert into test1 (num_col1) values ("+ float_param1 +")";

snowflake.execute(
    {sqltext:sql_command}
    );
return 'succes.';
$$ 
;
call rt(12.23::float);
```

error is like "JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: float_param1 is not defined in RT at ' "insert into test1 (num_col1) values ("+ float_param1 +")";' position 42 stackstrace: RT line: 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input parameter should be upper case inside the stored procedure.

var sql_command=
"insert into test1 (num_col1) values ("+ FLOAT_PARAM1 +")";

Comment: thanks for quick reply ,  after above change  it is giving error like "Execution error in store procedure RT: empty argument passed At Snowflake.execute, line 3 position 10"

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc1(float_param1 float)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var return_value = '';
var V_SQL = `insert into test1 (num_col1) values(:1)`;

var EXEC_V_SQL = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: V_SQL, binds: [ FLOAT_PARAM1 ]})
try{
 EXEC_V_SQL.execute();
 return_value = "success";
}

catch(err){
 return_value = "Error";
}

return return_value;
$$;

Comment: thanks ,it is working But why I am getting error " FLOAT_PARAM1"